# Specifying both 'fields' and 'form_class' is not permitted

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have the following form, which I want render it with Django crispy forms.

This is my views.py

```
class RehabilitationSessionCreate(CreateView):
    model = RehabilitationSession
    form_class = RehabilitationSessionForm()

    success_url = reverse_lazy('rehabilitationsessions:list')

    fields = ['patient','medical','therapist','status','date_session_begin','upper_extremity',
              'pain_extremity','affected_segment','movement','metrics','time_movement','games',
              'game_levels','iterations','errors_numbers_game','time_level_acomplished',
              'patient_behavior','observations','date_session_end','period',]

class RehabilitationSessionUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = RehabilitationSession
    success_url = reverse_lazy('rehabilitationsessions:list')
    fields = ['patient', 'medical', 'therapist', 'status', 'date_session_begin', 'upper_extremity',
              'pain_extremity', 'affected_segment', 'movement', 'metrics', 'time_movement', 'games',
              'game_levels', 'iterations', 'errors_numbers_game', 'time_level_acomplished',
              'patient_behavior', 'observations', 'date_session_end', 'period', ]
```

This is my `urls.py` project main file :

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^sesiones-de-rehabilitacion/', include('medical_encounter_information.urls', namespace='rehabilitationsessions')),
    # Call the medical_encounter_information/urls.py

]
```

This is my `medical_encounter_information/urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url, patterns
from .views import RehabilitationSessionCreate

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', RehabilitationSessionList.as_view(), name='list'),

    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$', RehabilitationSessionDetail.as_view(), name='detail'),

    url(r'^nuevo/', RehabilitationSessionCreate.as_view(), name='new'),

    url(r'^editar/(?P<pk>\d+)$', RehabilitationSessionUpdate.as_view(), name='edit'),

    url(r'^borrar/(?P<pk>\d+)$', RehabilitationSessionDelete.as_view(), name='delete'),

]
```

In my `forms.py` file I have:

```
class RehabilitationSessionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(RehabilitationSessionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', u'Save'))

    def save(self, commit=True):
        rehabilitation_session = super(RehabilitationSessionForm, self).save(commit=False)
        patient = self.cleaned_data['patient']

        if commit:
            rehabilitation_session.save()

        return rehabilitation_session

    class Meta:
        model = RehabilitationSession

        widgets = {
            'pain_extremity':forms.RadioSelect,
            'upper_extremity':forms.RadioSelect
        }
        fields = '__all__'
```

The template `medical_encounter_information/templates/medical_encounter_information/rehabilitationsession_form.html` is:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block title %}Crear Registro{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<div>
    {% crispy form %}
    {% csrf_token %}

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

When I type in my browser the url `http://localhost:8000/sesiones-de-rehabilitacion/nuevo/` I get the following:

```
 File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrhb_dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 138, in get_form_class
    "Specifying both 'fields' and 'form_class' is not permitted."
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying both 'fields' and 'form_class' is not permitted.
[11/Jul/2016 15:44:29] "GET /sesiones-de-rehabilitacion/nuevo/ HTTP/1.1" 500 100235
```

But, When I type in my browser the url `http://localhost:8000/sesiones-de-rehabilitacion/editar/1` I view the following:

[image]

Because the view `sesiones-de-rehabilitacion/editar/1` (`RehabilitationSessionUpdate`) is renderized, and the view `sesiones-de-rehabilitacion/nuevo/` (`RehabilitationSessionCreate`) is not renderized knowing that together take the same template?

Comment: What happens if you just drop the 'fields' meta property in your Create class-based view? This should be working and using the 'fields' meta property from the form.

Comment: Side note: in `RehabilitationSessionCreate` you set `form_class` to a form _instance_, not a form class. It should be changed to `form_class = RehabilitationSessionForm`.

Comment: @knbk It's True, such as says too @-raphv. Thanks to together for the information.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As the error says, you cannot set both `form_class` and `fields` for your view. You can either set `form_class`

```
class RehabilitationSessionCreate(CreateView):
    model = RehabilitationSession
    form_class = RehabilitationSessionForm  # Note you should *not* have ()
    success_url = reverse_lazy('rehabilitationsessions:list')
```

Or you can set `fields`:

```
class RehabilitationSessionCreate(CreateView):
    model = RehabilitationSession
    fields = ['patient', ...]
    success_url = reverse_lazy('rehabilitationsessions:list')
```

You shouldn't need to set `fields` and `form_class` at the same time, because you can set `fields` on the form itself:

```
class RehabilitationSessionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ['patient', ... ]
```